# Sending multiple string parameters to post request in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, post, request

I am using `Net::HTTP::Post` to send a request to a pre-determined url, like so:

```
my_url = '/path/to/static/url' 
my_string_parameter = 'objectName=objectInfo' 
my_other_string_parameter = 'otherObjectName=otherObjectInfo' 

request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(my_url)
request.body = my_string_parameter
```

However, I know that `my_url` expects two string parameters.  I have both parameters ready (they're statically generated) to be passed in.  Is there a way to pass in multiple strings - both `my_string_parameter` as well as `my_other_string_parameter` to a post request via Ruby on Rails?

EDIT: for clarity's sake, I'm going to re-explain everything in a more organized fashion. Basically, what I have is

```
my_url = 'path/to/static/url' 
# POST requests made to this url require 2 string parameters, 
# required_1 and required_2 
param1 = 'required_1=' + 'param1_value' 
param2 = 'requred_2=' + 'param2_value' 
request = request.NET::HTTP::Post.new(my_url)
```

If I try `request.body = param1`, then as expected I get an error saying "Required String parameter 'required_2' is not present".  Same with `request.body=param2`, the same error pops up saying 'required_1' is not present.  I'm wondering if there is a way to pass in BOTH parameters to request.body? Or something similar?

Comment: Please provide example of `my_url` and `my_string_parameter` variables/methods.

Comment: I've added in a few more details, but didn't want to give too much away.

Comment: You'd like to POST on local controller?

Comment: Not exactly, it's a static url. Sorry, I'll change it since I can see how that's pretty misleading.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
uri = URI('http://www.example.com')
req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri)
req.set_form_data('param1' => 'data1', 'param2' => 'data2')
```

Alternative

```
uri = URI('http://www.example.com/')
res = Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, 'param1' => 'data1', 'param2' => 'data2')
puts res.body
```

For more `request` like `Get` or `Patch` you can refer [This](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#top) offical doc.

Comment: Hm, I'm not using a form so not sure if this applies in this case.

Comment: `post_form` is HTTP class Method, you just need to pass a value in it

Answer (score 0):

You can send it like this.

```
data = {'params' => ['parameter1', 'parameter2']}
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(my_url)
request.set_form_data(data)
```

Comment: Hm, this didn't seem to work because the url requires specific names for the parameters, something like param_1_name=param_1_value and param_2_name=param_2_value

Comment: Please edit the question with the specific requirements.

Answer (score 0):

**If your params are string:**

```
url = '/path/to/controller_method' 
my_string_parameter = 'objectName=objectInfo' 
my_other_string_parameter = 'otherObjectName=otherObjectInfo'

url_with_params = "#{url}?#{[my_string_parameter, my_other_string_parameter].join('&')}"

request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(url_with_params)
```

**If your params are hash** It would be easier

```
your_params = {
  'objectName' => 'objectInfo',
  'otherObjectName' => 'otherObjectInfo'
}
url = '/path/to/controller_method'
url_with_params = "#{url}?#{your_params.to_query}"
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(url_with_params)
```

Comment: When I try either of these, I get "undefined method `bytesize' for #<Hash:>"